# Bootstrap affix nav wraps on small screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I have an affixed nav in bootstrap which works great, until you view on the iPhone. It is too wide for vertical orientation. I would like just the nav to "nowrap" and "overflow-x: scroll". I am utilizing all of

- Bootstrap's fluid layout
- Bootstrap responsive features
- 'affix'ed navigation

I thought I had just to `white-space:nowrap; overflow-x:scroll;` some part of the nav, but could not get it to work.

working great on wider media:
[image]

not so great on narrow media, trying to get a horizontal scroll on the nav ONLY (not the whole page):
[image]

Here's a fiddle. Resize the result pane until it is very narrow (like a vertical orientation iPhone screen): http://jsfiddle.net/dirkraft/HQJfb/2/

Answer (score 0):

well the issue you are having can be resolved by using media queries for iphone resolution like following :
Js fiddle with your example [http://jsfiddle.net/shail/HQJfb/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/HQJfb/6/show)

[image: iphone4]

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.row-fluid:after, .row-fluid:before {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.navbar .nav {
    margin: 0px;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    padding:10px 8px;
}
}
```